# Matrix of Letters

Tags: iphone, uiview

I am trying to create word search puzzle..I am using UIView model class to display letters in matrix form with image view..can any one tell me how to select letters from image view to make word and match it from original word or  should I use something other than image view??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you present each letter as a subclass of UIView you can use UITapGestureRecognizer. And don't forget to set userInteractionsEnabled to YES (for UIImageView default value is NO, so no taps deliver to either imageView or any of it's subviews).

Comment: If I am using Image of Letter A ,B ,c etc..then how Would I get letter?

Comment: There are several ways: you can use tag property of UIView, you can make a subclass of UIView with property. But! According to MVC paradigm you should not do it : ) You ought to have a model - matrix with letters, controller - that manage views and model, views - images of letters. So when you chose a letter, controller should calculate matrix indexes from coordinates (controller knows sizes of images) and asks model to get letter for given matrix indexes.